# Citing a country's constitution in OSCOLA style

Tags: constitutional-law

How do you cite a country's constitution in the the Oxford University Standard for Citation of Legal Authorities (OSCOLA) style?

Comment: That standard [doesn't seem to have anything to say on the matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_Standard_for_Citation_of_Legal_Authorities).

Comment: A standard would surely require all countries to have a written constitution, which they do not.

Answer (score 1):

OSCOLA 2006 says to cite foreign legislation (presumably including constitutions) using that jurisdiction’s style.

Comment: The Blue Book provides extensive guidance on how to cite foreign legal authorities which would probably be considered acceptable under OSCOLA 2006 in the absence of other knowledge about how to do so from legal sources in that country. https://www.legalbluebook.com/ Also, per the link in the comments: "An online supplement (developed for the third edition) is available for the citation of international legal cases, not covered in the main guide." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_Standard_for_Citation_of_Legal_Authorities